# magento2: How to swap two elements in header

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, header

I am new in magento and I am creating a custom theme for Magento 2.

I try to swap two elements, header wrapper and header content.

Default header:
[image]
I'm trying to get this:
[image]

I create file `frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`, and try swap it with `<move element="header.panel" destination="header.container" before="-"/>` but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find below code in `default.xml` file and add highlighted part **(after="header-wrapper)**.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
    <container name="header.panel.wrapper" htmlClass="panel wrapper" htmlTag="div" after="header-wrapper">
        <container name="header.panel" label="Page Header Panel" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="panel header">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="skip_to_content" template="Magento_Theme::html/skip.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">contentarea</argument>
                    <argument name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Skip to Content</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="switch/languages.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
    </container>
    <container name="header-wrapper" label="Page Header" as="header-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">189</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">64</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

**OR**

```
<move element="header.panel" destination="header.container" after="header-wrapper"/>
```